# C++: __aligned(__alignof__) causing problems with char array data?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, alignment

**Tl;dr:** A char array my code is accessing that was previously pointing to an expected string value now has unexpected characters before the string. My current theory is this is somehow being caused by a change to the alignment of the char array and am trying to figure out if I'm right and how to fix it.

I'm trying to maintain a Linux kernel module written in C++. It's been a long time since I worked in C++, so I'm a bit stuck on what I'm currently seeing.

We have a separate utility outside the kernel modue that stories a key in the kernel keyring. Later the kernel module looks up that and compares it to the expected key value. Here's the lookup method:

```
#include <linux/key.h>
#include <keys/user-type.h>

int read_key(char *key_desc, char *expected_key) {
    struct key *key;
    struct user_key_payload *key_payload;

    key = request_key(&key_type_user, key_desc, NULL);
    key_payload = rcu_dereference(key->payload.data[0]);

    return strncmp(key_payload->data, expected_key, key_payload->datalen));
}
```

This code is currently working on most of the kernel versions we support. But recently there was a kernel upgrade in one particular OS, and now my strncmp call is failing to find a match. It seems like the data is offset in some way. Like if key_payload->datalen = 16, and expected_key = "1234567890123456", then key_payload->data = "abcdef1234567890123456". Which since I'm comparing the first 16 characters obviously will not match, but will if I start at key_payload->data[6] instead. So far key_payload->datalen is still the correct expected string length. It's just key_payload->data that's changed on the new kernel version.

I've looked at a few patches in the new kernel I think might be related to the problem. One obvious difference I've found is [this one](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v4.4.212&id=d76ef3c980247096164e47b708658f054347c04e). Before the patch the user_key_payload object from  looked like:

```
struct user_key_payload {
    struct rcu_head rcu;        /* RCU destructor */
    unsigned short  datalen;    /* length of this data */
    char        data[0];    /* actual data */
};
```

But after it looks like:

```
struct user_key_payload {
    struct rcu_head rcu;        /* RCU destructor */
    unsigned short  datalen;    /* length of this data */
    char        data[0] __aligned(__alignof__(u64)); /* actual data */
};
```

I don't know if this is what actually causing my problem but it seems like an obvious place to start looking. I've never worked with the aligned or alignof keywords before. I've read some articles about alignment, but it's all a lot lower level than I've been working with for some years now. Does anyone know if there's a way the alignment of user_key_payload.data could be messing up the expected memory address of the key data, and how to figure out where my expected data actually is?

Comment: "I'm trying to maintain a Linux kernel module written in C++." Do you mean C?

Comment: The patch you mentioned would introduce 6 bytes of padding between `datalen` and `data` on architectures with 64-bit pointers where pointers and `u64` are aligned to 8-byte boundaries (e.g. the x86-64 architecture), so that is likely to be related to the problem as you suspected. Kernels are not supposed to break userspace stuff, but perhaps there is something odd about the way your separate utility stores keys in the kernel keyring.

Comment: "Do you mean C?" Probably. It has been A While. Our utility stores the key using the add_key() method from the keyutils package. I'm not discounting that there's a problem on the add_key() side, but the keyutils version didn't change on the working vs non-working kernel, and I've tried upgrading keyutils in concert with the kernel but still saw the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char data[0]` means the pointer just after the struct. It is widely used in the kernel to indicate the variable-length payload coming after the header.

`__aligned(__alignof__(u64))` aligns data to 8-byte (64-bit) boundary. It means, for instance, if the required size to store all fields in `struct user_key_payload` is 10 bytes, then the struct gets padded to occupy 16 bytes (2*8).

Hence, if the kernel threats the data 8-byte aligned, but your module - doesn't, then that "abcdef" is the padding you are reading from.

When compiling the module, always make sure to include the same versions of header files that are used to compile the kernel.

Comment: @gzoi It might not be a breakage of the user API. After all, userspace does not use `struct user_key_payload`. However, the kernel API is not stable. It can and does break frequently between releases, and 3rd party module code needs to deal with that.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah, I have had to fix many a problem when the API breaks in a kernel upgrade :). We generally handle that by setting a number of compile time flags based on the kernel version, and compiling the kernel module locally on the kernel to be used. In this particular case though the kernel module is precompiled, so I'm trying to figure out how to tell we're running on a kernel with this patch, and how to handle it once I do know that. Not saying it's impossible or even that difficult. Just new to me.

Comment: @IanAbbott I believe we are talking about kernel module (i.e., kernel space), not a userspace program. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @PooSH My comment was in reply to a comment that suggested possible user API breakage. The comment I was replying to has been deleted so mine is a bit out of place now!

Comment: Sorry! I deleted my comment because I thought it was unclear, but then I forgot to go back and post an updated version of it. But yes, everything I've been talking about has been in the kernel module, so if I sounded like I was talking about the user API I probably misspoke. I've been able to implement a workaround now that I understand the problem. I appreciate both of your help.